# Which software to track employee hours for a small business?

Tags: windows, android, web-apps, ios

I am looking for a time tracking/payroll management integrated software for my small business.

Multi platform support is a must, mobile and PC. There are so many options so I'd really appreciate personal recommendations, and why you like the specific product.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just made an account to answer this question so I hope I'm doing it correctly.

I am in HR in a medium sized business, and we use [Deputy](https://deputy.com) to manage both payroll and employee shifts.

I'm happy to recommend it as we're satisfied with it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can benefit from [Toggl](https://toggl.com/). Now they are changing their name Toggl to Toggl Track. It supports multi-platforms. You can get the desktop app, mobile app, and try the web app for free. There are more than one way to track time when using Toggl. You will have access to one-click timers, background tracking, autotracker, calendar integration

Other than that you can use Time Doctor.