# Application to manage working hours of employees

Tags: business-intelligence

I am looking for a software based solution that will integrate with our restaurant's roster and allow us to schedule/track/manage employee hours. Bonus points if this also integrates/handles payroll compliance.

I have used TSheets in the past but it was a bit expensive for the above features.

Answer (score 1):

I asked this question last month and received an answer:

https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/77292/70647

This answer recommended the use of a tool called [deputy.com](https://deputy.com). We've been using it since then as a paid customer, and it's met our needs. I haven't much experience with TSheets, but Deputy does offer payroll integration (we use it) and staff rostering in an easy to use manner.